# VBA how to find entire number in a string and set to variable

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list that was copied from a 'table of contents' page to column D. Unfortunately, each cell contains the chapter number, chapter name, and the page number.

3.14.4   chapter name placeholder.140

Sometimes there is a space between the page number and the last character. other times there is not.

I've tried

```
Function john(txt As String) As Long
Dim x
x = Split(Trim(txt), Chr(32))
john = Val(x(UBound(x)))
End Function
```

Which does work but I'd like to be able to apply this to the chapter number as well afterwards.

```
Private Sub FIND_LAST_NUMBER()

Dim A As String
Dim B As Integer
Dim C As String
Dim D As String

x = 3

Do While ActiveSheet.Cells(x, 4).Value <> ""

A = Range("D" & x).Value
A = Trim(A)
B = Len(A)
For Position = B To 1 Step -1
    C = Mid(A, Position, 1)
    'MsgBox C
    If C <> " " Then
        D = Right(A, B - Position)
        Range("E" & x).Value = C
    GoTo LastLine
  'Exit Sub
End If
Next Position

LastLine:
    x = x + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

but I'm trying to figure out how to get all of the number instead of only the last digit of the page number from the original cell

I am obviously not getting something here.

Any tips or tricks will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Is there always a space after the chapter number and before the chapter title?

Comment: I still don't quite understand your input format, are there dots between the numbers or not?

Comment: Try regex pattern `^(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+).*(\d+)$`.

Answer (score 0):

One, admittedly not very beautiful solution I can think of right away would be to use `Replace` to remove all non-numeric characters.

```
Dim str As String

str = Replace(str, " ", "") '<- to remove the random spaces
str = LCase(str) '<- making everything lower case

For i = 97 To 122
    str = Replace(str, Chr(i), "")
Next i
```

`Chr(i)` with i from 97 to 122 will be every Character of the standard Alphabet.
This does not work if special Characters appear in the Chapter Name String. If the Chapter name contains numbers these will remain, but you could detect that case because `UBound` of the split array will be 1 greater than usual.

Also if you can quickly scan all the cells with your data for other unwanted Characters like - / or whatever might occur, you can also get rid of them with `Replace`

Performance of this solution might not be great but for a quick fix it might do..